# Initialising a DListNode

Tags: java, linked-list

When I define a `DListNode` I need three variables. I can't figure out which ones are which.

`DListNode doubleCur = new DListNode(var1,var2,var3);`

What does each var correspond to? (I understand that one is the node and the two others are the links, but in which order are do I define them?)

Answer (score 0):

`DListNode`is a custom class, so it depends on how it has been implemented.

Anyway, how about the following?

```
...
...
...
public Object item;
protected DListNode prev;
protected DListNode next;

/**
 *  DListNode() constructor.
 *  @param i the item to store in the node.
 *  @param p the node previous to this node.
 *  @param n the node following this node.
 */

DListNode(Object i, DListNode p, DListNode n) {
   item = i;
   prev = p;
   next = n;
}
```

Looking for "DListNode" on Google, first and second results already present options ;)